# Insertion and match function in linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

What seems to be the problem with the function insert here? I can't get my head head around it.

It should be a simple insert function in a linked list data structure, where the variables need to get copied over to memory allocated and if there no errors it should return 0.

```
int insert(char *s, char *p, char *o) {
    struct node *new = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    new->Subject = s;
    new->Predicate = p;
    new->Object = o;
    struct node *temp = head;

    while (temp->next != NULL ) {
        if (strcmp(temp->next->Subject, s) > 0) {
            break;
        } else if (strcmp(temp->next->Subject, s) == 0) {
            if (strcmp(temp->next->Predicate, p) > 0) {
                break;
            } else if (strcmp(temp->next->Predicate, p) == 0) {
                if (strcmp(temp->next->Object, o) > 0) {
                    break;
                } else if (strcmp(temp->next->Object, o) == 0) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    new->next = temp->next;
    temp->next = new;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What happens when the list is empty? `head ` should be null and you are setting `temp ` to it (line 6), then accessing to `temp->next ` (line 8) without checking if `temp ` is null. You need to consider that case apart.

Comment: BTW, I think it would be beautiful if you implemented a `compare` function, receiving two node pointers and returning an int (-1 means first arg is smaller, 0 means args are equal, 1 means first arg is bigger). Your `while ` loop would have a `int comp = compare(temp->next, s)`, and then break or return or continue depending on that result.

Answer (score 0):

`temp->next` is still `null` or garbage value
use :

```
new->next = temp
```